# How to format a table in RStudio Notebook output

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio, rnotebook

I am using an RStudio R Notebook in the visual editor and would like to format the default table output for a tibble.

```
tibble(letters, number=1:26*1000*rnorm(1))
```

For me it looks like this:
[image]

E.g. I would like to define the number of digits and the `big.mark` separator or the column width, paging, or number of lines.

Also it would be great, if you can show me a way to set these options globally for the notebook.

Thanks

Comment: `options(digits = 3)`